# Class instance methods? object methods?

Tags: objective-c, oop, instance

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_%28computer_programming%29#Class_methods):

> Class methods are methods that are called on a class (compare this to
>   class instance methods, or object methods).

Could you guys please clarify `object methods` to me?
And `Class instance methods` are `Instance methods` if i'm correct?

Comment: This question makes me a Sad panda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to rephrase the above Wikipedia quote more clearly in the context of Objective C:

Class methods are methods belonging to the class, rather than to an instance of a class.

Instance methods are methods of an instance of a class; which is often referred to as an object.  Sayng "class instance methods" obviously refers to this, but is confusing.

Comment: Thank you very very much Mr. Paul Lynch.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Class instance methods = Object methods because Object == Class instance.
An object is an instance of a class. From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_%28computer_programming%29):

> In object-oriented programming, a class is a construct that is used as a blueprint 
>   to create instances of itself – referred to as class instances, class objects, 
>   instance objects or simply objects.

Answer (score 3):

In objective C class method is used by just class name, you dont need to create a instance of class to access these methods.. But for object methods you need to create an instance of the class which means creating a object of class..
In objective C +/- identifiers are used for it;

```
@interface AClass: NSObject

+ (void)classMethod;
- (void)instanceMethod;

@end

[AClass classMethod];

AClass *object = [[AClass alloc] init];
[object instanceMethod];
```